# assigning value to an object when referencing it by a string within a for loop

Tags: r, assign

I often struggle with understanding how to assign values in `R` within loops.  The desired behavior seems simple to me, but I clearly don't have a good grasp on the subtleties of evaluation and assignment in `R`.

For example, I've got a bunch of data objects that I want to add a comment to *each* object (they are unrelated and so using them together in a list beyond this assignment does not make sense). Here's a MWE

```
my_comment <- paste0("these objects were created on ", date())

obj1 <- "content1"
obj2 <- "content2"

obj_l <- list(obj1, obj2)

for(obj in obj_l) {
comment(obj) <- my_comment
}

## get 'NULL', but want "these objects were created ..."
comment(obj1)

## get 'NULL'
comment(obj_l)

## assignment is only made to temp variable 'obj'
## This makes sense, but not the desired outcome. 
comment(obj)
```

I imagine the solution will look something like the following pseudo code

```
obj_l <- c("obj1", "obj2")

for(name in obj_l)
 unknown_function(name, comment, my_comment, unknown_args)

}
```

or

```
modify(obj_l, my_comment, unknown_syntax)
```

If my pseudo code is on track, can someone help me with the `unknown_` parts?

Comment: Although both of the answers are good, I'm not sure if they actually respond to the OPs question? The way that I understood it was that the OP **wants** the objects to be commented not the list. Hence the whole reason for the for loop. If this isn't possible, as per Gregor's answer then that should be made a bit clearer in the answers present.

Comment: If that is what is wanted the question is not clear.

Comment: I mean, it's not impossible (clearly), but if that's the goal the `list` is pointless. (And using a `list` in a case like this is a good practice, whereas having sequentially named variables in your environment usually makes things harder every step of the way.)

Comment: I am sorry my question was unclear.  I have tried revising it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more reading of help pages and trial and error, here's my solution

```
obj1 <- "content1"
obj2 <- "content2"

obj_l <- c("obj1", "obj2")

comment <- '"my comment!"'

for(x in obj_l) {
    my_exp <- paste0("comment(", x, ") <- ", comment)
    parse(text = my_exp)
}

comment(obj1)
# [1] "my comment"
```

Comment: OMG! This is my first functional use of eval and parse!

Comment: Slick way of using them as well as paste since it pulls the object out of the list.

Comment: Using `eval` unnecessarily is discouraged.

Comment: @GregorThomas Actually, I'm an old pro at writing poor code. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Any of these work to comment the components of `obj_l` or in the case of #3 to produce a new list with comments added.  We show that the object has been changed for #1 but the others are the same.

```
# 1
obj1 <- "content1"
obj2 <- "content2"
obj_l <- list(obj1, obj2)
for(i in seq_along(obj_l)) {
  comment(obj_l[[i]]) <- "some comment"
}
dput(obj_l)
## list(structure("content1", comment = "some comment"), 
##   structure("content2", comment = "some comment"))


# 2
obj1 <- "content1"
obj2 <- "content2"
obj_l <- mget(c("obj1", "obj2"))
for(nm in names(obj_l)) {
  comment(obj_l[[nm]]) <- "some comment"
}

# 3
obj1 <- "content1"
obj2 <- "content2"
obj_l <- list(obj1, obj2)
obj_2 <- lapply(obj_l, `comment<-`, "some comment")
```

If what you wanted was to comment `obj1` and `obj2` then

```
# 4
obj1 <- "content1"
obj2 <- "content2"
nms <- c("obj1", "obj2")
e <- .GlobalEnv # environment with objects
for(nm in nms) comment(e[[nm]]) <- "some comment"

# 5
obj1 <- "content1"
obj2 <- "content2"
obj_l <- mget(c("obj1", "obj2")) # named list w obj1, obj2 elements
lapply(obj_l, `comment<-`, "some comment") |> list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, I want to assign the comments to the original objects.  i think I got it figured out, though.  I appreciate your help, nonetheless.

Comment: These add a comment to each component of the list which appears to be what the question is asking but if that is not what you wanted them I have added code at the end that adds a comment to each of the objects.  Suggest you clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

With lists in a loop, it's usually easier to loop over the indexes or the names, not the actual objects:

```
for(i in seq_along(obj_l)) {
  comment(obj_l[[i]]) <- my_comment
}

comment(obj_l[[i]])
# [1] "these objects were created on Wed Nov  9 10:55:27 2022"
```

And you have added a comment to the item **in the list**, don't expect `obj1` to have a comment. (Better not to think about `obj1` at all, what you have is `obj_l` which has 2 elements, `obj_l[[1]]` and `obj_l[[2]]`.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, I want to assign the comments to the original objects.  i think I got it figured out, though.  I appreciate your help, nonetheless.

Comment: Oops.  I had intended to put comment on my answer.  Have deleted.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at answering the actual question without using the `comment()` function.

See Below:

```
create_comment <- function(object, comment) {
  
  new_object <- list(Object = object, Comment = comment)
  return(new_object)
}

test <- map(c(obj1, obj2), create_comment, comment = my_comment)
```

Instead of using the `comment()` function I built a function that creates a named list object for each individual object. This makes it so that I can create a large list with all of my stored objects and it also stores the character string `my_comment` within the list.

the output from test shows...

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$Object
[1] "content1"

[[1]]$Comment
[1] "these objects were created on Wed Nov 09 16:04:04 2022"


[[2]]
[[2]]$Object
[1] "content2"

[[2]]$Comment
[1] "these objects were created on Wed Nov 09 16:04:04 2022"
```

I can then use `[[i]]` to access my objects

For example:

```
test[[1]]

$Object
[1] "content1"

$Comment
[1] "these objects were created on Wed Nov 09 16:04:04 2022"
```

And I can further access my individual comments or object by using the `$`

```
test[[1]]$Comment

[1] "these objects were created on Wed Nov 09 16:04:04 2022"
```